# How to display the last 10 lines that are added to a log file with `tail`?

Tags: command-line, tail

I need to display the last 10 lines of a log file with `tail`. I currently us this command:

```
tail -n 10 -f /var/log/myapp/access.log
```

but it is not working as expected, as it doesn't follow new lines as they are added.

What's the command to do this?

Comment: Works perfectly when I do it. I get to see 10 lines already in the file and new lines get added on screen. Mind that `-f` also includes `-n 10` by default.  Plus that the `-n 10` is for the 1st view. New lines will get added on screen; It is not going to only show 10 lines when new lines get added.

Comment: Same here. This is a correct command. If you stop the `tail -f` using Ctrl + C, and immediately enter the same command, do you see lines that weren't added the first time? That would be unusual.

Comment: Maybe your source application does not flush file output immediately after it is produced.

Comment: I can reproduce this with `nvim`. If I create a file and add content using `nvim`, the added content doesn't appear in `tail -f` after saving the file, nor after quitting it. I have to stop the `tail` command and restart it to see the added content. If I add content using `echo`, e.g. `echo "this is a line" >> file.txt`, the content is immediately reflected in `tail -f`.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog is your `nvim` recreating the file for some reason? Does `tail -F` work for you?

Comment: @muru Hmmm... It appears so (`nvim` recreating the file). Adding a line with `nvim` and using `tail -F` displays `tail: 'file.txt' has become inaccessible: No such file or directory` followed by `tail: 'file.txt' has appeared;  following new file` and then the contents of the file with the added lines displayed.

Comment: Might be a bug in Neovim. AFAIK Vim only recreates a file when it can't write to it.

Comment: @muru Just checked. With Vim it works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do it in this way:

```
watch -t -n 1 tail -n 10 /var/log/myapp/access.log
```

parameters are used for `watch`:

```
-t, --no-title         turn off header
-n, --interval <secs>  seconds to wait between updates
```

Comment: Not a good solution imo. What if there are more than 10 lines for each second? You will miss lines. `tail -f` should be just fine, and if not, we need to fix that.

Comment: watch -t -n 0.0001 tail -n 10 ./output.txt